# Zip: invalid characters in path (but works after manually re-zip)

Tags: windows-10, java, zip, maven

I have a tag/release name that I get from github. The repo is named name-testing. It contains a java automation test work. We are using a windows server to run the tests. 
When used automatically or added directly (download the zip and upload it in our ci/cd tool), it doesn't work ("Zip: invalid characters in path "). However, when manually un-zipped then zipped again the folder, it works.

I'm not sure what is happening. They both have the same structure, and if one passes, I don't see why the other doesn't.

Edit: We have another tag/release taken from github automatically, called name-8s, and this one has no such problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Some zip tools just ignore files that can't be unziped, e.g. because of invalid names on Windows.

Comment: @Robert Hello! I have edited the post, we have another project that works. That one is a yaml (mainly) so quite different. Could java/maven conflict with some windows rules?

Comment: Why don't you just post the links to the projects with problems?

Comment: I can't, those are company github.